# Xcode 4 warning "Expression result unused” for NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, warnings

I'm just trying to do my usual data transfert. I define my NSMutableURLRequest then call

`[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

This used to be ok with Xcode 3 but Xcode 4 warns me about "*Expression result unused*" on that line.
The request does work but I would like to find a way to get rid of the warning.

I suppose I could store the connection in a variable but I don't really need it and I can't see the point of setting it to `nil` the next line (although this would remove the warning)

Please note: I'm not 100% sure if it's Xcode 4 or the fact ARC is enabled.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

When a function returns a result that you don't need you can cast it to void to eliminate the compiler warning:

```
(void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I haven't used ARC yet so I can't say if this is a good idea, before ARC you would need to keep this pointer result somewhere so you could release it.

Comment: This did remove the warning and the function is still working as required so all good! It's the first time I see this cast to void. Is it good practice? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because it documents the fact that you know there is a result being returned but you don't need that result.

Comment: I still get the warning when I am attempting to use a #define based logging macro:  `#if SHOW_DEBUG_LOG
# define DEBUG_LOG(x,...)  NSLog(@"Debug Log: "x, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
# define DEBUG_LOG(x,...)  (void)(x); do { (void)(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
#endif`

Answer (score 34):

progrmr's answer is correct, but here's an even cleaner way to do it:

`[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

This doesn't cause a warning, even if you don't cast the result to void.

Comment: Deprecated as of iOS 10. :(

Answer (score 3):

Someone should be responsible for that `NSURLConnection`. It is not needed to store the connection but it is better coding if you do. The problem is that after you created our `NSURLConnection` no one has a pointer to that created instance which should not be the case.

Let's assume the following example:

1. your instance of `ClassA` is creating an instane of `NSURLConnection`
2. your instance of `ClassA` is beeing released and dealloced
3. `NSURLConnection` is still alive and will fire the delegate to your deallocated instance.

To solve that problem you should store the instance of `NSURLConnection` and should release that connection if your instance of `ClassA` is being dealloced which results in deallocating the instance of `NSURLConnection` as well.

Comment: I can't release it as ARC is on. Is it not what ARC is supposed to do automatically, deallocating the pointer?

Comment: but the problem still exist semantically: `NSURLConnection` knows your instance of `ClassA` but nobody knows your instance. There is a relationship between both instances and this relationship needs to be managed ;) But if you dont save the pointer to `NSURLConnection` then nobody has a pointer to it and either ARC is deallocating the connection immediately or never. If you save the resulting pointer then the warning will not appear and you have a better coding-design and you are then able write more reliable code:`connection:(NSURLConnection*)con didSth{if(con != self.curCon) return;}`