# Getting warning with asynchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

am trying to avoid this warning am getting using `NSURLConnection`:

```
-(void)goGetData{
    responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somefile.php"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [responseData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@",error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableArray *qnBlock = [responseString JSONValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < [qnBlock count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"%@",[qnBlock objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}
```

The warning is at line:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Warning is:

```
Expression result unused.
```

The entire code runs fine but i'm just taking preventive measures.

Comment: Please go through this link. It could be  Duplicate of your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914990/xcode-4-warning-expression-result-unused-for-nsurlconnection

Answer (score 4):

Both approaches allocate an object.

With alloc,

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

you are responsible for releasing it.

With connectWithRequest,

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

it is retained by the autorelease pool. My guess is that since it is retained by the autorelease pool, you don't need a handle to release it and the compiler is satisfied that the autorelease pool has the handle.

With alloc, the compiler is probably expecting you to keep a handle for releasing later. So it flags this as a warning.

The fact is that the delegate method gets the handle, whether you keep one explicitly or not. So you can release it with the handle passed to the delegate method. The warning is really spurious then, but its just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Instead of:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: It worked. Please spare me sometime to explain why the additional parenthesis was causing the warning... Thanx...

Comment: You were allocating and initializing an object of the class `NSURLConnection`, although you were not storing it anywhere... With the solution I gave you, you are using a class method (you are not allocating an object of the class `NSURLConnection`)

Comment: If you think this answers has helped you, please mark it has correct. It will help you in the future (rises your % of accepted answers) and it will tell future users that might come here, that this has helped you.