# 'Expected expression' errors

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I'm getting Expected expression errors on the following code:

```
 (void) for(t; t < kPlatformsStartTag + kNumPlatforms; t++) { //error here
 CCSprite *platform = (CCSprite*)[batchNode getChildByTag:t];

CGSize platform_size = platform.contentSize;
CGPoint platform_pos = platform.position;

max_x = platform_pos.x - platform_size.width/2 - 10;
min_x = platform_pos.x + platform_size.width/2 + 10;
float min_y = platform_pos.y + (platform_size.height+bird_size.height)/2 - kPlatformTopPadding;

if(bird_pos.x > max_x &&
   bird_pos.x < min_x &&
   bird_pos.y > platform_pos.y &&
   bird_pos.y < min_y) {
    [self jump];
    }
}

 (void) for(t; t < kCloudsStartTag + kNumClouds; t++) { //error here
CCSprite *cloud = (CCSprite*)[batchNode getChildByTag:t];
CGPoint pos = cloud.position;
pos.y -= delta * cloud.scaleY * 0.8f;
if(pos.y < -cloud.contentSize.height/2) {
currentCloudTag = t;
     [self resetCloud];
} else {
    cloud.position = pos;
    }
}
```

The error is found where the "for" code is.  I put the (void) code in because I will get an Expression result unused error.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's the generated error exactly? and the error without the `void` before the `for`?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: Also, learn the basics of C (possibly using a book or a tutorial). You have to be aware of the fundamental elements of the language, we are not here to spoon-feed them to you.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Thanks for the advice which didn't help me with my problem.  I'm using objective-C on the xcode engine.

Comment: @rullof - The error I get without the void is Unused Entity Issue - Expression result unused.  I got the void solution from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914990/xcode-4-warning-expression-result-unused-for-nsurlconnection

Comment: in `for(t; ... ; ...){}` t is an expression, not a declaration. Declare it (and initialize it) and you'll be Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got answers about the bogus `(void)`, but not about the unused expression.

> ```
> for(t; t < kCloudsStartTag + kNumClouds; t++)
> ```

The initial expression here, `t`, has absolutely no effect, and for that reason has no business being present at all. The value of `t` is read and immediately discarded, and any decent compiler will optimise that by not even bothering to read `t`. You do not need an expression here. You can remove it, and write

```
for(; t < kCloudsStartTag + kNumClouds; t++)
```

although personally, I might be tempted to go with a `while` loop instead.

*Edit*: reading your code more closely, your code *seems* to need to give `t` an initial value.

```
for(t = 0; t < kCloudsStartTag + kNumClouds; t++)
```

Either way, your attempt to suppress the warning without understanding what the warning was telling you wasn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The `(void)` before the `for` loop does not make sense.

Comment: The error I get without the void is Unused Entity Issue - Expression result unused.  I got the void solution from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914990/xcode-4-warning-expression-result-unused-for-nsurlconnection

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `(void)` before the `for` loop because it's not a valid c syntax. You can't solve an error with another error.

You may ask the question : Why puting `(void)` before the `for` loop prevented the unused expression error. Well that's because the debugger didn't reach it. and it doesn't know for what is `for` as he expected a resulted value from it to cast it to `void`.

When the compiler is generating the error: `Unused Entity Issue - Expression result unused`. That's means that your program is evaluating an expression without using it.

In your case at the `for` loop if the `t` variable is already initialized as you want it, you shouldn't put it at the first part as it will be considired as an unused expression.

```
for(; t < kPlatformsStartTag + kNumPlatforms; t++) { // keep the first expresion empty
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think, user2984757 is not talking about warnings because of unused variables but of unused results of an expression (like e.g. calling a function returning an `int` without using its result) instead. Which, in my opinion, is a useless warning anyway, because in C, almost every expression contains an expression which is evaluated only for its side-effects (`x=y;` has an unused result, for instance, and writing `(void)(x=y)` is stupid), there's nothing generally wrong with ignoring the result of a non-void expression.

Comment: @mafso Tanks i just missed it since he didn't cleared the problem.